# Error starting SQL server service as Built in account Local System

Tags: sql-server

I'm not able to start SQL server service as Local System, Local Service or Network Service.

> Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in.
> For example: blank passwords aren’t allowed, sign-in times are limited,
> or a policy restriction has been enforced. [0x8007052F]

Using my own administrator domain account, it starts fine.

[image]

Funny thing is, SQL server agent service starts fine with all 3 accounts.

Answer (score -1):

Quite sure that if you update the password the problem will be gone.

The root cause might reside in:

- **Windows Group Policy:** Windows policies are responsible for some of the actions that your system performs. The error message is, sometimes, due to a particular Windows Group Policy which stops the Remote Desktop Client to expose sign-in credentials to the remote host. Disabling the policy seems to fix the issue.
- **No Password:** In some cases, the error message can also occur if the user account that you are using to establish a remote connection doesn’t have a password. In such a case, you will have to either set a password or just disable this policy as well.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "update the password". I'm trying to use Local System, which has no password by default

Comment: @tinker, yes but you logged in with a user for that session. change that password.